# Understanding permutations of $S_4$ which correspond to symmetries of a regular tetrahedron

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, representation-theory, rotations, symmetry

I'm trying to understand values of the character of the representation of $S_4$ corresponding to the symmetries of a regular tetrahedron (whew, that's a mouthful!). One illustrative video is found [here](https://youtu.be/POh_-mdBHVw?t=312), where the different conjugacy classes of $S_4$ acting on the regular tetrahedron are discussed.

What I'm struggling with is understanding how you can deduce how the $x, y, z$ values are mapped to each other in the case of a single two cycle $(1, 2)$, two two cycles $(1, 2)(3, 4)$ and the four cycle $(1, 2, 3, 4)$. Let's consider for example the single two cycle $(1, 2)$: We'd like to flip (I'm referring to the illustrations of the video) the swap the vertices of the lower right edge of the tetrahedron while keeping $3$ and $4$ fixed. Does the lecturer deduce that $x\mapsto x$ by turning the tetrahedron over, so that the vertex $4$ points downwards? And then there are the other cycle types I mentioned...

Comment: The single two-cycle comes from a reflection in a plane through one edge of the tetrahedron. which swaps the two vertices not on that edge.

Comment: @MarkBennet While I do accept this, I still can't visualize the action itself. Do you happen to know some good illustration about this?

Comment: For the pair of two-cycles you can rotate around a line which passes through a pair of opposite edges. The four-cycle is more challenging since it is an "opposite" isometry (involving a reflection) - you can tell this because the cycle is an odd permutation. Do you have a physical tetrahedron - or can you make one?

Comment: @MarkBennet No I don't and I can't :(. However, the lecturer (in the video of the link) suggested viewing the four-cycle as rotations involving two planes which pass through the midpoints of two pairs of chosen edges.

Comment: The four cycle cannot be made with two rotations. You can easily make a tetrahedron - cut out an equilateral triangle and fold across folds through midpoints of sides. Secure with tape. Two would be better because you can number vertices in opposite orientations (one a reflection of the other). You ill find you get only twelve of the 24 elements of $S_4$ from rotations. You can put an arbitratry face on the base and rotate to three orientations. I recommend a physical model as this will help you (strangely) to develop your abstract thinking by helping you to spot where your intuition is wrong.